# How to add small separator between buttons in custom ribbon (Ribbon x : XML)?

Tags: excel, ribbonx

I wanted a small separator to appear between buttons in custom ribbon tab. But the `<separator id="MySeparatorE1" />` always draws large vertical separator.
How can we get small separator ***as circled in picture*** to appear between the buttons ?

[image: Info]

*I want a small seperator between Sample1 and Sample2 of figure (In figure both are written sample though) !*

```
</group>
            <group id="customgroupF" label="EDIT SECTION">
               <dropDown id="dropDownF1" label="Hello:" sizeString="B_300*300" getItemCount="GetItemCount1" getItemLabel="GetItemLabel1" onAction="onaction1" getSelectedItemIndex="ItemSelectedIndex1" />
               <dropDown id="dropDownF2" label="Hi:" sizeString="C_300*300" getItemCount="GetItemCount2" getItemLabel="GetItemLabel2" onAction="onaction2" getSelectedItemIndex="ItemSelectedIndex2" />
                   <box id="box1" boxStyle="horizontal">
                  <button id="custombuttonF3" label="Sample1" screentip="Increase" onAction="Macro4" imageMso="UpArrow2" />
                  <button id="custombuttonF4" label="Sample2" screentip="Decrease" onAction="Macro4" imageMso="DownArrow2" />
                  </box>
               <box id="box2" boxStyle="vertical">
                  <button id="custombuttonF1" label="Run1" showLabel="false" screentip="Edit1" onAction="Macro4" imageMso="MacroPlay" />
                  <button id="custombuttonF2" label="Run2" showLabel="false" screentip="Edit2" onAction="Macro4" imageMso="MacroPlay" />
               </box>
            </group>
```

Comment: `Separator` is no valid child element of `box`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/fb660d68-051e-4a86-ab97-e0d93b32817e - it seems there is no way to have this little separator.  Although the screenshot within documentation of `buttonGroup` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-customui/d9f60979-43e7-40e6-bd21-1f9693600c21 seems to have these little separators it doesn't show up as well ...

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Ribbon engine determines the positions of controls that you add to a group. If you want to define the layout of the controls with more precision, you can group the controls within one or more boxes. When you create a box, you specify its orientation (horizontal or vertical). A group can contain multiple boxes, and you can include vertical dividers between the boxes. The vertical dividers are created by using the `separator` control, which is used only for vertical boxes. For example:

```
<group id="CustomGroup2" label="Vertical Boxes" 
   insertBeforeMso="GroupClipboard">
  <box id="box3" boxStyle="vertical">
    <button id="buttonB1" label="Button1"/>
    <button id="buttonB2" label="Button2"/>
  </box>
  <separator id="separator2"/>
  <box id="box4" boxStyle="vertical">
    <button id="buttonBA" label="ButtonA"/>
    <button id="buttonBB" label="ButtonB"/>
    <button id="buttonBC" label="ButtonC"/>
  </box>
</group>
```